# uint32_t as vector index has better performance than size_t in 64-bit

Tags: c++, performance, vector, size-t

I have some performance critical code similar to this:

```
void func(std::vector<int>& v, size_t i)
{
  while(i > 0)
  {
    // do something with v[i]
    // compute next i   
  }
}
```

After I changed the type of `i` from `size_t` to `uint32_t`, the run time of the code decreased by more than 10%. When this function is called, its input type is always `size_t`. The code was compiled in 64-bit using Clang. The function is inlined by the compiler in multiple places of a more complicated context so it is hard to compare the assembly code. Are there any general ideas why this could happen?

---

I did some further investigation. First, it does not seem Clang can optimize the code well when `uint32_t` is used as vector index. See the following example:

```
void func(std::vector<int>& v, size_t i)
{
  for(auto j = i; j < v.size(); ++j)
  {
    v[j] = 0;    
  }
}
```

If we change `size_t` to `uint32_t`, an awful large amount of assembly will be generated: https://godbolt.org/z/1qrrrs

As for my performance critical code, when `size_t` is used, Clang can do more aggressive loop unrolling. However, it turns out such unrolling has worse performance, possibly due to some branches are not hit as often as expected. I did some unrolling manually, and now the performance between `size_t` and `uint32_t` are the same.

Comment: Are you sure you've enable optimizations?  Using the Godbolt Compiler Explorer with x86-64 clang (trunk) and -O2, I get the same code regardless of the type chosen for the index.  https://godbolt.org/z/nPbev7

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yes I enabled optimization. In this example, if you move `i /= 2;` after `v[i] = 0;`, the assembly will be different. I think if the function is inlined in a certain context, it could result in more difference.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I have figured out what happened and updated my examples to show the assembly difference.

Comment: Part of the problem is that clang has to generate code that will also work if `v.size()` is greater than 2^32, in which case the loop needs to be infinite.  So it's not so easy for it to reduce it to a simple `memset` as it does for `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any general ideas why this could happen?

- It's possible that 32 bit operations are faster on the CPU
- It's possible that the change in the size of the variable caused stack to be aligned differently in relation to a memory page boundary, and/or caused some particularly critical piece of data or instruction to not be missed due to cache conflict, resulting in incidental change in performance.

Comment: It is very possible to be incidental. However, I wonder if using 32-bit instead of 64-bit index could always increase the chance for additional data/instruction to be fit into the cache. If that is the case, shouldn't we always use 32-bit index in performance critical code?

Comment: @Fan What if conversion from 32 bit to 64 bit is sometimes more expensive? What if we have a vector larger than 4 gigabytes? We cannot make such assumptions in general-

Comment: Conversion from 32-bit to 64-bit takes at most 2 instructions if no spare register is available. So it is like a tradeoff between 2 instructions and 4 byte cache? As for maximum possible vector size, it will not be a problem if we know it beforehand. In most cases, there is a limit to the input data of an application.

Comment: It turned out the issue was loop unrolling. I have updated my question with the new finding. It seems we should really stick with `size_t` as vector index.

Comment: It is also quite surprising to see how Clang is unable to optimize the assembly when `uint32_t` is used as index.